# Google App is published on closed test track, play store wont load download page

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps

I've set up users to complete internal closed testing via the google play console.
Some users are able to access the download link and download the app via the play store as expected.
When others click the link to download, it launches the play store app, then never loads and displays no error message.

I've tried troubleshooting the devices with no luck, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Closed beta is of 2 types

1. Only available to Testers whose email IDs are saved in the console as testers.
2. Any user with the play store link to your app can become a tester

you need to change it in settings first, I guess you have not added the Email IDs of your testers, so add their email IDs to the console then check again

Comment: Thanks Trinadh,
I have all the users set up the same way, all can access except one. 
The user experiencing the issue has tested the app before and is now having trouble redownloading a new build.